# I am getting an error when using C# in a 2D Unity game, saying that 5 of my names "does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting an error when using C# in a 2D Unity game, saying that 5 of my names "does not exist in the current context".

I have tried changing the code, and finding ways online, but nothing works.

My code is:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public enum type { platformer, topDown };
    public type moveType;
    public float moveSpeed, jumpHeight;
    public bool onGround = false;
    private type platformer;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.right * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.left * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
        }

        if (moveType == type.platformer && Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0 && onGround)
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }

        if (moveType == type.topDown && Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.up * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
        }
        if (moveType == type.topDown && Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < 0)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.down * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D obj)
    {
        if (obj.gameObject.tag == "ground")
        {
            onGround = true;
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D obj)
    {
        if (obj.gameObject.tag == "ground")
        {
            onGround = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I get 5 errors. 4 of them look the same, but they're not. (Check the numbers in brackets.) They are:

"Assets/Scripts/MovementManager.cs(24,13): error CS0103: The name `transform' does not exist in the current context"

"Assets/Scripts/MovementManager.cs(28,13): error CS0103: The name `transform' does not exist in the current context"

"Assets/Scripts/MovementManager.cs(33,13): error CS0103: The name `GetComponent' does not exist in the current context"

"Assets/Scripts/MovementManager.cs(38,13): error CS0103: The name `transform' does not exist in the current context"

"Assets/Scripts/MovementManager.cs(42,13): error CS0103: The name `transform' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Ah, right. You may need to tell the script to look at the gameObject first. Try adding `gameObject.transform` and `gameObject.GetComponent` to your script.

Comment: That mustn’t be necessary, usually that code would work just fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend to put any enum definition into a separate file.

Your error is coming from the fact that you are defining an enum inside your class and placing a `semicolon` after the definition. Removing the semicolon probably resolves your error. However as I said I recommend to put the entire enum into a seperate file. If you don't want that, I'd recommend putting the enum outside your class definition. That way it is still usable in other scripts.

E.g

```
public enum MoveType
{
    platformer, 
    topdown
}
```

Also try to steer clear from naming any class or enum 'type' , since Type is an existing class and easily leads to confusion and/or errors.